# Property ngClass is not provided by any applicable directives nor by div element

Tags: html, angular, angular-cli

If i want to use ngClass, ngStyle or ngIf i get the following errormessage:

[image: Error Message]

My app.module.ts includes BrowserModule and CommonModule imports. And my Components are in the declarations.

I tried restart ng serve and npm install.

[image: ngModule]

Any Ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried building your project ? Do you also have this error in JS console when you are accessing your webpage?

Comment: yes i rebuild the project. surprisingly the browser developer tools dont show any error. the app also runs like expected. the only thing was happening is that my intelliJ still shows an error on ngClass:
Property ngClass is not provided by any applicable directives nor by div element

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you said, everything works fine when your project is builded/launched in your browser. So it's an issue with your IDE.

You have multiple solutions

- update your Intellij, if it's already updated ...
- ... invalidate your cache, if it's still doesn't work
- delete your node module and recreate it (this fixed your issue here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-51326)
- reinstall it/create new project
- or ... switch to VSCode while Intellij is fixing your bug

Comment: it was fixed by deleting the node_modules folder and reinstall

Comment: Good to know! It's easier than reinstalling Intellij

Comment: For me it only worked after upgrading Intellij ..

Answer (score 1):

In case the answer of @Pilpo doesn't work for you, try deleting the `.idea` Folder and restart IntellJ.
That did work in my case.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn´t work for me.

I tried thousend things but still not working.

Switch to VSCode was the best option

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error using PHPStorm,
it suggests me to "Import Ngstyle" which works.

The change was an import of NgStyle in my component.ts file and @component{imports} section :

```
import {NgIf, NgStyle} from "@angular/common"; <<<

@Component({
  selector: 'app-face-snap',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    NgIf,
    NgStyle, <<<
  ],
  templateUrl: './face-snap.component.html',
  styleUrl: './face-snap.component.scss'
})
```

I'm just beginning AngularJs so it may not be the best solution according to the framework.

Answer (score -2):

You can add this `<!--suppress ALL-->` at the top of the page until Intellij solves this problem.

```
<!--suppress ALL-->
<button [ngStyle]="{'color': color}"></button>
<div [ngClass]="'first second'"></div>
```